# How to show dynamic text in modal in react native?

Tags: react-native

Here is my code. Hope you will understand.

```
class SuperAdmin extends Component {
    state = {
        modalVisible: false,
        organizationNames: [ 
            {
                 "id": 1,
                "name": "Org 1",
                "activated": true
            }, 
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Org 2",
                "activated": false
            }
        ]
    };

    setModalVisible(visible) {
        this.setState({modalVisible: visible});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Block style={ styles.blockStyle }>
                <Header title="Organizations" />
                <ScrollView>
                    { this.state.organizationNames.map((item, index) => { 
                        return (
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('OrganizationMembers')}>
                                <Card borderless shadow style={ styles.cardStyle }>
                                    <Block style={ styles.spaceBetween}>
                                        <Block>
                                            <Text h5 style={ styles.textStyle }>{item.name}</Text>
                                            <Text muted>{item.activated ? 'Activated' : 'Deactivated'}</Text>
                                        </Block>
                                        <Block>
                                            <Button 
                                                round 
                                                size="small" 
                                                style={ item.activated ? styles.btnOn : styles.btnOff } 
                                                onPress={() => { this.setModalVisible(true);}}  
                                            >
                                                { item.activated ? 'Online' : 'Offline' }
                                            </Button>
                                            <Modal
                                                animationType="slide"
                                                transparent={false}
                                                visible={this.state.modalVisible}
                                            >
                                            <Block style={ styles.myModal }>
                                                <Card style={ styles.myCard }>
                                                    <Text style={ styles.modalTextStyle}>

                                                        { item.activated ? 'Do you want to make this organization offline ' : 'Do you want to make this organization online ' }
                                                        ?
                                                    </Text>

                                                </Card>

                                            </Block>
                                        </Modal>
                                    </Block>
                                </Block>

                            </Card>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    )
                }
                )}
            </ScrollView>

        </Block>
    );
}
}
```

I have created a component where a modal opens when a button is clicked. There are two buttons. One is online button. And the other is offline button. When I click the online button I want to show this text in the modal: "Do you want to make this organization offline". And when I click the offline button I want to show this text in the modal "Do you want to make this organization online".

But any button I click it shows the same text in the models: `"Do you want to make this organization online".` How do I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are rendering Modal the wrong way, create a state for seletedItem, onPress set the state with the current item...
use the following code...

```
state = {
    modalVisible: false,
    organizationNames: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Org 1',
        activated: true,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Org 2',
        activated: false,
      },
    ],
    selectedItem: null,
  };

  setModalVisible(visible, item) {
    this.setState({ modalVisible: visible, selectedItem: item });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Block style={styles.blockStyle}>
        <Header title="Organizations" />
        <ScrollView>
          {this.state.organizationNames.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() =>
                  this.props.navigation.navigate('OrganizationMembers')
                }>
                <Card borderless shadow style={styles.cardStyle}>
                  <Block style={styles.spaceBetween}>
                    <Block>
                      <Text h5 style={styles.textStyle}>
                        {item.name}
                      </Text>
                      <Text muted>
                        {item.activated ? 'Activated' : 'Deactivated'}
                      </Text>
                    </Block>
                    <Block>
                      <Button
                        round
                        size="small"
                        style={item.activated ? styles.btnOn : styles.btnOff}
                        onPress={() => {
                          this.setModalVisible(true, item);
                        }}>
                        {item.activated ? 'Online' : 'Offline'}
                      </Button>
                    </Block>
                  </Block>
                </Card>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            );
          })}
        </ScrollView>

        <Modal
          animationType="slide"
          transparent={false}
          visible={this.state.modalVisible}>
          <Block style={styles.myModal}>
            <Card style={styles.myCard}>
              <Text style={styles.modalTextStyle}>
                {!this.state.selectedItem?.activated
                  ? 'Do you want to make this organization offline '
                  : 'Do you want to make this organization online '}
                ?
              </Text>
            </Card>
          </Block>
        </Modal>
      </Block>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you have rendered mutliple modal.

You have used modal in a loop so it will be like this,

```
<TouchableOpacity  ....
 ....
 ...
 for 0th index
....
<Modal>
....
</Modal>
</TouchableOpacity>
<TouchableOpacity  ....
 ....
 ...
 for 1st index
....
<Modal>
....
</Modal>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

internally this will be there.
now that each time modal component is there it has only one state for visibility.

so every modal is opening there but last one is on top.

so you need to remove modal from loop, put it outside,

and whatever details you want to put in modal based on condition set them into state.

eg., take message named state and when button clicks change this state with setState.